# Ramsey's theorem exclusion OR?

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Consider Ramsey's theorem:

For any $s, t \ge 1$, there exist $R(s, t) < \infty$ such that any graph on $R(s, t)$ vertices contains either an independent set of size $s$ or a clique of size $t$. In particular,

$$R(s, t) \le \binom{s+t-2}{s-1}$$

---

Is this an exclusive condition? In other words, can an independent set of size $s$ exist along side a clique of size $t$ in a graph with $R(s,t)$ vertices?

Comment: You can have both but it's easy to show that you can't guarantee having both (for $s,t>1$)

Comment: @Joffan: I think you (like me at first) may have missed the point: the OP is asking about a graph with exactly $R(s, t)$ vertices. $R(2, 2) = 2$ and a graph with 2 vertices can't have both an independent set with 2 vertices and clique with 2 vertices. $R(3, 3) = 6$ which gives enough room for both. I don't know what happens for larger $s$ and $t$.

Comment: Yes, you need $R(s,t)\ge s+t-1$ to allow both of course, and in general only $s,t>2$ is interesting, since $s=2$ just means that the graph is not complete and $t=2$ just requires an edge.

Comment: Any graph on $R(3,3)=6$ vertices contains an independent set or a clique on $3$ vertices, and it's an **inclusive** or. For example, consider the graph $G=(V,E)$ with $V=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and $E=\{ab,bc,cd,de,ea,fa,fc,fd\};$ it has a $3$-point clique $\{c,d,f\}$ and a $3$-point independent set $\{b,e,f\}.$